# Complex variable arguments checking at runtime

Tags: python, arguments, typing

Let's consider a function like this:

```
def f(*args, **kwargs):
   ...
```

`*args` are a variable number of arguments that must be:
(an object, a float, a float), possibly repeated N times,
followed by 0 to N' objects.

For example this is a valid call:

```
f(my_obj, 0, 1, other_obj, 2, 3, obj3, obj4)
```

but this is invalid:

```
f(my_obj, other_obj, 2, 3)
```

This function is exposed to users through a Python shell.
So, there is value in checking user input -- I am using
the `typeguard` library that works with type annotations
(like mypy).

I am trying to use `typing` module to write the proper annotations...
I thought I could at least express the constraint on the groups of 3 args
like this:

```
@typeguard.typechecked
f(*args:Tuple[Any,float,float])
```

But it does not work.
And in anyways I have no idea how to add the constraint on the following objects.

Of course I can craft myself some code to check arguments, but I am sure something better exists for cases of complex variable arguments sequences (either a clever use of the `typing` module or another Python lib ?)

Comment: Python annotations are not to raise errors when arguments doesn't match the given type. Python is dynamically typed as you know and types are mostly for readability. You can run a type check on your code with `mypy` but the code itself will not throw an error if you do not make assertion.

Comment: @Nf4r yeah I know... But this is particular case of a function exposed to users through  a shell, it is useful to do type checking at runtime. I am using typeguard, I updated my question

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create interface (a'ka ValueObject) composed of any object, float and float and say that the function accepts the list of these objects?

Comment: You could create a custom class that handles validation on initialization and throws error if something happends.

Comment: @Nf4rit would not be convenient for people writing the commands... f(ValueObject(o,2,4), ValueObject(x,1,2)) is much more verbose than f(o,2,4,x,1,2)

Comment: This won't be possible to do with PEP 484 type hints. Fundamentally, PEP 484 assumes your `*arg` and `**kwarg` parameters are homogeneous -- are all the same type. If this isn't the case, you'll either need to leave the types as `object` and manually implement the checks yourself or restructure your code. For example, I'd personally make the function signature something more like `f(tups: List[Tuple[Any, float, float]], objs: List[Any])`. It may be a bit more verbose to write, but it'll also likely be much easier for future readers to understand code that uses this function.

Answer (score 1):

What I meant by making the validation:

```
def _validate(a, b, c):
    assert isinstance(b, float), f"{b} is not a float!"
    assert isinstance(c, float), f"{c} is not a float"

def _validate_args(args):
  if (len(args) % 3 != 0): # wrong number of args
    raise ValueError("Arguments must be passed in pack of 3")
  for idx in range(0, len(args), 3):
      a, b, c = args[idx: idx + 3]
      _validate(a, b, c)

def func(*args, **kwargs):
  _validate_args(args)

func(1, 2.0, 3, 1, 2, 3)
```

> AssertionError: 3 is not a float

You can make any message you want.

Comment: How would you check for additional objects after the packs of 3 ? f(o,1,2,oo,3,4,x,y,z) is valid

Comment: Depends on what do you want to achieve with additional arguments?